# Freemarker - template preprocessing

Tags: java, freemarker

I was wondering, whether there is a way to preprocess freemarker template with some rules - I would like to add some syntactic sugar, which not really a directive, nor method.

Fo instance I have variables, which I print like this:

```
${item.getLocale(currentLocale).name}
${item.getLocale(currentLocale).text}
${item.parent.getLocale(currentLocale).name}
${item.parent.getLocale(currentLocale).text}
```

Obviously, the `getLocale` construct makes the whole expression pretty ugly. What I would like to achieve is to be able to write:

```
${item.l.name}
${item.l.text}
${item.parent.l.name}
${item.parent.l.text}
```

So that all the `.l.` would be during compilation rewritten to `.getLocale(currentLocale)`.

Is there some nice way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much why object wrapping exists in FreeMarker; you can present the data to the templates in a custom way. I suppose `item` belongs to a specific Java class. So you could extend the `DefaultObjectWrapper` or `BeansWrapper` to wrap those items specially, and then use `Configuration.setObjectWrapper(new YourObjectWrapper())` once where you initialize FreeMarker. (See the source code of `DefaultObjectWrapper` as an example of customization; it extends `BeansWrapper` to wrap XML nodes, Jython object, etc., specially.) Thus when you have `${item.name}` in the template, it's a call to `YourHashModel.get("name")` on the Java side (where `YourHashModel` extends `freemarker.template.TemplateHashModel`), and in that `get` method you can have `return new SimpleScalar(item.getLocale(currentLocale).get("name"))` or like.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is a solution, because in the real case the item might contain different kinds of collections in which I would like to use this `.l.` as well. I would have to traverse all the inner objects, which might not even be yet initialized. Consider `item.parent.parent.parent.parent.l.name`. I think template preprocessing might be easier solution.

Comment: But the last `parent` in your example still have a `getLocale` method, right? I guess that comes from some `Interface` or `Class` that you can wrap specially. How many `parent`-s are before that that aren't special doesn't mater, because (normally) you will use the same object wrapper for everything. It doesn't mater that you go through `HashMap`-s, `List`-s, arrays or whatever, the wrapper of the root object will be still watching.